Switched Capacitor Non-Inverting Amplifier
I have been studying switched-capacitor circuits recently. I have come across one question with regards to the switched-capacitor non-inverting amplifier circuit shown below. It is made up of transmission gate switches, I1-I3 and has two non-overlapping clocks, as indicated on the schematic as Phase 1 and Phase 2.
My question is:

Does it make a difference the way I connect the switch? For example, does it make a difference if I connect source of MOS to Vi or drain of MOS to Vi? Source of MOS to opamp input or drain of MOS to opamp input?


Thank you very much
